# MS Access function taking long time to complete stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

```
create procedure _update_ticket
  @date datetime
as
begin
  update t set
    I_S1_O = (select count(*) from W_Data w where [Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]< @date and w.[Product_Name] = t.[Product_Name]), 
    I_S1_R = (select count(*) from W_Data w where [Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]>= @date and w.[Product_Name] = t.[Product_Name]), 
    I_S1_Re = (select count(*) from W_Data w where [Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [R_Group] <> '1' and [R_Group] is not NULL and w.[Product_Name] = t.[Product_Name]), 
    .....
  from ATicket t
end
```

When I execute the above stored procedure with the below function from Access form it is taking long time... waited more than half an hour. If I open the pass through query it is updating within few secs. please advise

```
Function AppCount()
Dim cdb As DAO.Database, qdf As DAO.QueryDef
On Error Resume Next
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set qdf = cdb.QueryDefs("Get_A_Ticket")
qdf.SQL = "EXEC dbo.Update_A_Ticket_Count '" & CDate(Forms!Home!Txt_StDate) & "'"
qdf.Execute
Set qdf = Nothing
Set cdb = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Is the stored procedure in SQL Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely all the subqueries in the update statement.  Sometimes, you can fix this problem just by creating the right indexes.  But that is hard in this case, because of all the inequalities in the conditions.

Instead, you can presummarize the data in `W_Data` and then join these back for the updates:

```
update t set
    I_S1_O = sumt.I_S1_O, 
    I_S1_R = sumt.I_S1_R,
    . . .
from ATicket t join
     (select Product_Name,
             sum(case when [Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]< @date
                      then 1 else 0
                 end) I_S1_O,
             sum(case when [Priority] = 'S1' and [Type] <> 'R' and [A_Group] <> '1' and [C_Date]>= @date                          then 1 else 0
                 end) I_S1_R
      from W_Data w
      group by Product_Name
     ) sumt
     on t.Product_Name = sumt.Product_Name
```

Comment: thanks . I will try this method and let you know in case of any queries. Also please tell me how this query is completing within a few seconds when i run the function manually or opening the pass through query manually.